# S-Link Hub's type c port does not work

Tags: external-monitor, displayport, usb-c

I have Dell XPS 9350 and displayport capable monitor. I've used type c to displayport converter and have no problem with it. However, I bought [this](http://www.swapp.com.tr/swapp/dosyalar/urun/82/112.jpg?m=1476287505) product and connected my converter to hub's type c port, but I can't get any output on my monitor. How can I solve this problem?

Here is my `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` output when I connect the hub:

```
Feb  9 18:33:21 instantcrush-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [ 2562.318098] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Feb  9 18:33:21 instantcrush-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [ 2562.446517] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1a40, idProduct=0101
Feb  9 18:33:21 instantcrush-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [ 2562.446543] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
Feb  9 18:33:21 instantcrush-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [ 2562.446549] usb 3-1: Product: USB 2.0 Hub
Feb  9 18:33:21 instantcrush-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [ 2562.447755] hub 3-1:1.0: USB hub found
Feb  9 18:33:21 instantcrush-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [ 2562.447868] hub 3-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
```

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:5682 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:6412 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:07b9 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The hub has USB type c 2.0. Can it be cause of the no output?

Comment: Is the USB-to-DisplayLink converter compatible with USB 2.0? What's the output of `lsusb` when you plug it in directly?

Comment: There is no output when I just plug in converter. Only kern.log gives output when I connect hub to type c port.

Comment: Huh? How can a USB device work that isn't detected by the kernel? Again, what's the output of lsusb when you plug it in directly?